# Report: Page visits, unique visitors, new visitors (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a report that should include monthly page visits (sessions afaik), unique visitors (new users?) and new visitors (compared to all time before the selected date).

Is it possible with Google Analytics to show new users per month. I mean users that the page hasn't seen before?

I know that there is the new vs. returning users feature but if I add new and returning users I end up with the number of sessions. Does not make any sense to me. That would mean that the number of sessions equals unique visitors, right?

Comment: Is it possible, that session equals unique visits? New users can be separated into single session and multi session users. Both add up to new users though. New users and returning users add up to sessions. That could mean that sessions = unique visits; new users = 1st time visitors; returning users = nth time visitors?